# React testing with Enzyme, componentDidMount updating HTML()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Say we have a component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $                  from "jquery";
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        $('#empty_p_tag').text('hello')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>This is a component</p>
                <p id ="empty_p_tag"></p>
            </div>)
    }
}
export default App;
```

and we want to test that the p tag with the id `empty_p_tag` now says 'hello' in the tag. How do we do this with enzyme and jest?

```
it('should render hello', function () {
    const app_wrapper = mount(<App/>);
    const p_tag = app_wrapper.find('#empty_p_tag').text();
    expect(p_tag).toBe('hello');

});
```

When running this test I get the response:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "hello"
    Received: ""

      4 |       const app_wrapper = mount(<App/>);
      5 |       const p_tag = app_wrapper.find('#empty_p_tag').text();
    > 6 |       expect(p_tag).toBe('hello');
        |                     ^
      7 | 
      8 | });
```

I am unsure of where I'm going wrong with this? Should I storing the p_tag element in the props and states section of a constructor? Further, I'm trying to avoid using mount but when I run with shallow it's not happy.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, as described [here](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1708), `componentDidMount` runs after the mount. Not only but according to [this](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1708#issuecomment-417870639) post, direct manipulation of the DOM is an antipattern in react. Instead, you could use `state`. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/enzyme-jest-example-dp5ux?file=/src/index.test.js) a working example.

What I have done is define a `text` in `state` component. Then, on `componentDidMount`, I call `this.setState` to set `text` to `hello`.

So, your component becomes:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         text: ""
      };
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ text: "hello" });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>This is a component</p>
                <p id ="empty_p_tag">{this.state.text}</p>
            </div>)
    }
}
export default App;
```

And your test becomes:

```
it('should check `componentDidMount()`', () => {
      const app_wrapper = mount(<TestComponent />);
      const p_tag = app_wrapper.find("#empty_p_tag").text();
      expect(p_tag).toBe("hello");
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying.  This unfortunately isn't working. I still get the same result. I've looked at the link you've said, it's pretty dated. Do you think I should store this information inside the app constructor instead?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Ciao, sorry for late answer but today was a very busy day. I try to rewrite my answer better.

Comment: thank you :) This is what I did. thank you for confirming.

Comment: No problem and sorry for my previous mistake. Have a nice day :)